# Is it possible to remove a table tag on a specific html location using only css

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

Is it possible to remove a table tag on a specific HTML location using only CSS? **I have access only to the CSS file unfortunately.**

I want to remove the image (which say "LOUIS INVESTORS RELATIONS") on the blue background here: http://louis.stockwatch.com.cy/nqcontent.cfm?a_name=fstatement&lang=en

It would be great if I could remove the whole table that contains that image.

Is it possible, and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now use to this**

```
table tr:first-child td:nth-child(2) img {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the whole table that contains that image means removing pretty much everything.

If you mean to remove the `<td>` that the image is within, that is possible, if you assume that no other `<td>` has an attribute with the `background-color` being set to `#576f9c`:

http://jsfiddle.net/YY98W/

```
table td[bgcolor="#576f9c"] { display: none; }
```